# Amazon EMR: How to get faster startup time and concurrent execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, batch-processing, emr

I'm looking for a platform for tons of small batch jobs where one job finishes within 20 seconds in most cases. I also gave AWS Batch a try but it doesn't suit my use case due to this problem: [forums.aws.amazon thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=268685&tstart=0) , so I'm giving EMR a try as another possible option.

I created an EMR cluster which consists of three m3.xlarge instances and contains Spark applications **(Spark: Spark 2.2.0 on Hadoop 2.7.3 YARN with Ganglia 3.7.2 and Zeppelin 0.7.3)**. I tried executing a step, which does almost the same as "Write a Spark Application" example on the EMR release guide, on the cluster. The code is: [sparksandbox](https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/sparksandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/sandbox/Main.java) .

An execution of the code above finishes within about 3 seconds on my laptop, but executing the code on EMR where there is an active cluster takes about 1 minute. As far as I see, more than 50 seconds are taken to reach the code which I wrote. And the steps only get executed serially. In other words, only one step becomes Running at the same time.

here are my questions:

1. Is there any way to make startup time for a job shorter?
2. Is there any way to execute multiple jobs concurrently on a cluster?

Or, is my use case not suitable for Amazon EMR?

[Originally I posted this question on Amazon Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=269381) but I haven't got any answer yet.

Comment: What do your batch jobs do? Do they require the resources of EMR?

Comment: @JohnHanley What my job does is something like this: parse a proprietary format binary file on S3 => do some filtering and manipulating => create (around 10 to 20) files and upload them to S3. I'm not sure what you mean by "the resources of EMR", but what I want to achieve here is that improving overall performance, maintainability and reducing cost of our batch processing which is written in single-threaded manner and running on bare EC2.

Comment: By "the resources of EMR", I am asking do you need a distributed platform. Amazon EMR is not really designed for small short lived batch jobs. You mention "bare EC2". What instance size are you using? Note: I doubt that you will save money moving from EC2 to EMR.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm using m3.medium with some auto-scaling based on the number of remaining jobs. I doubt it too, actually but I have to make it clear why it doesn't suite our use case, and hopefully find a better solution.